# swedish characters encoding failure when inserting data to mysql database from a webservice

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I tried to insert swedish characters from a webservice,
My code like this

```
Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->open("http://ws.aldoc.eu/ws/mekafrance/menu.alx");
    $j= 4;
    $id = 6;
    $idp = 6;
    while($xml->read()){
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == "Menuitem")
    {
        $product = $xml->expand();
        $product = new SimpleXMLElement('<Menuitem>'.$xml->readInnerXML().'</Menuitem>');
        $menucode = $product->menucode;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into `ps_category_lang`(`name`) values ( :name)");        
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);   
    $name =  mb_convert_encoding((string)$product->menu,"utf-8");

    $stmt->execute();
            }
           }
```

When i look into name field it show me something like this "AC/KlimatanlÃ¤gg".

the field encoding is utf8_general_ci, and the database also.
The file has utf-8 encoding, i set the header to utf also.

Comment: anytime you see `Ã` show up in text, you've got a charset encoding problem. something's mangling the text somewhere in the rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will go away if you open menu.alx with notepad++ and set the encoding on the entire xml file to UTF-8.

Comment: menu.alx is the url of the webservice is not mine

Comment: I solved the problem by refering to prestashop configuration file require('config/config.inc.php');